# How can I keep track of files processed while using map?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm using the map function with pandas to read in files with multiprocessing like

```
files = glob.glob('C:\Desktop\Folder\*.xlsx')
def read_excel(filename):
    return pd.read_excel(filename)
file_list = [filename for filename in files]
pool = Pool(processors = 4)
pool.map(read_excel, file_list)
```

But the problem is that whereas before I was using a for loop and could have a counter

```
count += 1
```

for each iteration through the loop and print the count / len(files) to get a sense of how far along the process is, I can't do that here. I realize with multiprocessing it could get a little funky but there should be some way to implement this.

Comment: Are you just trying to see if all the files have been processed - maybe `Pool.join()`. BTW `file_list = [filename for filename in files]` is just the same as `file_list = list(files)`.

Comment: I'm trying to keep track of what's the running count of processed files as they each take awhile to process and there are a lot of them

Comment: Use a `multiprocessing.Value` to create a shared `counter`.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is possible while using the map function. Will I have to revert to the for loop?